# everytime I put a figure, latex puts this huge space between the figure and the next text

Tags: graphics, floats

I have a huge problem with the figures in my report, I don't know why everytime I put a figure, latex puts this huge space between the figure and the next text. here's an example:

[image: here's an example of what happens] Please help

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,openany,pdflatex,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{layout}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%\usepackage{a4wide}
%---PACKAGES-------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{makeidx} \makeindex
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}                        % Lenny, Conny ,Bjarne, ejne, Glenn, Sonny
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{shadethm}
\usepackage{shadbox}
%\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage[french]{minitoc}
\usepackage{lettrine}
%\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,vmargin=3cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{color,framed}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=3cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{titletoc} % pour la table des matières 
%\usepackage{fourier}
%\usepackage{courier}
%\usepackage{setspace}  
%\usepackage{ulem} % pour les textes souligné 
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=violet,bookmarks=true]{hyperref} % pour les lien url

%---------- LES-COMMANDES --------------------------  


\newcommand{\thecompte}{\roman{compte}}  
\newcommand{\K}{\mathbb{K}} 
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}} 
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}} 
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}} 
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}

\newcommand{\implique}{\Longrightarrow}
\newcommand{\equivalent}{\Longleftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\reunion}{\displaystyle\bigcup} 
\newcommand{\intersection}{\displaystyle\bigcap} 
\newcommand{\vers}{\longrightarrow}
\newcommand{\inter}{\cap} 
\newcommand{\union}{\cup} 
\newcommand{\A}{\forall} 
\newcommand{\E}{\exists} 
%---THEOREMES-------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{break}
{\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{exo}{Exercice}}
\newshadetheorem{thm}{Th\'eor\`eme}[section]
\newtheorem{df}{D\'efinition}[section]
\newtheorem{rmq}{Remarque}[section]
\newtheorem*{proof}{Preuve}
\newtheorem{ex}{Exemples}
\newshadetheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section]
\newshadetheorem{pro}{Propriétés}[section]
\newshadetheorem{lm}{Lemme}[section]
\newshadetheorem{cor}{Corollaire}[section]
%\newtheorem*{nota}{Notations}
\newtheorem{pb}{Probl\`eme} 


%----En t\^ete et pied de page ------------

\pagestyle{fancy} \fancyhf{} % efface tout ce qu'il y avait avant 
 %\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\leftmark} 
 % LO = gauche/impair ; RE = droite/pair 
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\rightmark} % RO = droite/impair ; LE = gauche/pair 
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} % C = centré  
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{2pt}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=17 cm]{recouvrement.png}
\caption{}
\end{figure}
```

---

**Edit** (by touhami: answer converted here)

@touhami in some places here's what happens, even the other texts which are not part of the figure are not in place. SO i don't really think it's matter of space inside the figure, because i changed all my figures making sure there's no excess of white space, but the problem remains!!
[image: SO i don't really think it's matter of space inside the figure, because i changed all my figures making sure there's no excess of white space, but the problem remains!!]

Comment: The space is a result of some tex code in your file, if you do not show the code it is very hard to guess what is causing it.

Comment: The most probable cause is white space in the image. Try doing `\fbox{\includegraphics[<options>]{<file>}}` (use the real options and file name) and you'll see what TeX thinks the dimensions of the image are.

Comment: the packages are not that relevant to your problem which is either white space in your image file or specified in your document, but looking at your packages, you load a4wide twice (once is more than enough:-) you load inputenc twice you loac color twice you load graphics twice (as it is included by graphicx)

Comment: Let me throw my pinch of salt: `a4wide` should be avoided, all the more so as `geometry` is loaded.

Comment: when i delete a4wide, the theorems and propositions are written vertically, i tried avoiding it but it didn't work the way i wanted.

Comment: Even with `geometry`? Oh! b.t.w., `shadetheorem` is not a good solution: it can't break across pages, if necessary. Use `mdframed` or `framed` since you load `ntheorem`, for instance.

Comment: If you open `recouvrement.png` in the default image viewer, is there a lot of whitespace at the bottom? If yes, that's the problem, and you need to crop your image.

Comment: try replace `recouvrement.png` with `example-image`

Comment: `example-image` is an image that exists with `graphicx` package I suggest to use it to see if there is no space that's mean the space is in your figure.

Comment: in the `\figure` your first command is `\centering`.  but the graphic isn't centered -- it's left-aligned.  to me that says there is excess white space, and if there is excess white space on the right, there is almost certainly some at the bottom as well.  try enclosing it in an `\fbox` (as already suggested by egreg) to see what's really there.

Comment: i already did that and i just checked one more time, but i got the same result; i'm starting to go crazy .... :'(

Comment: Could you make your image available?

Comment: sorry i don't know how to do that here. Could you please try with any image u got and see if u get the same problem ?

Comment: Your document does not compile.  You are missing a `\begin{document}` and an `\end{document}`.  When I put that in, along with a *.png screen grab of your figure, it compiles fine, with appropriate spacing, after commenting out `\usepackage{shadbox}` which my texlive installation does not seem to find. `\caption{peut \'ecrire}` works as expected. Why `\caption{}` in your MWE?

Comment: what we try to tell you is that the white space is part of the figure that why the suggestion of `\fbox`  if the white space is inside the frame (box) that 's mean it's part of the figure 2nd suggestion replace your figure with onther one that we know is fine if the white space go that 's mean it's part of your figure. The best is to edit the image.

Comment: @LAILA excuse me, I add your answer as edit (update) to your question because it not an answer, please delete it.

Comment: @LAILA yes your right the problem is not as i think. Please add an example that compile and produce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First, as a man who has been typesetting French documents in France, I strongly recommend using direct Unicode input of your accented chars. Instead of `\c ca br\^ ule`, write `ça brûle` as usually; you have `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` on your side!

Second, for an MWE, get rid of all those extra packages. See if any of them is causing trouble. For example, `shadbox` was not even present on my system (TeXLive 2016), so I commented it out.

And this is a thing that works normally (with your preamble without that `shadbox` line):

```
\begin{document}

La plume de ma tante...

\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=17 cm]{recouvrement.png}
    \caption{La plume que ma tante utilise quotdiennement (en coupe) pour créer des titres qui occupent plusieurs lignes}
\end{figure}

...est sur le bureau de mon oncle.
\end{document}
```

[image: Page output with proper image size]

Are you sure your PNG file does not have any borders? I used this file as `recouvrement.png` (guaranteed to have no redundant borders; see how it almost occupies the width of your document):

[image: Recouvrement image for insertion]

I do suspect that the PDF or PNG graphics might have white borders (if they were produced in an unorthodox way). Try the PNG image above and see if it helps.